# Laravel conditional where with eloquent

Tags: laravel

I've got basic function that I'm passing simple parameter:

```
public function template($person)
{
      $offers = Offer::where([
          ['person', $person],
          ['published', true],
      ])
      ->orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate(9);   
 }
```

now I want to make it confitional, if there is a parameter or not:

```
public function template($person)
{
   if ($person) {
      $offers = Offer::where([
          ['person', $person],
          ['published', true],
      ])
      ->orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate(9);   
   } else {
      $offers = Offer::where([
          ['published', true],
      ])
      ->orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate(9);   
   }
}
```

this works, but it is not a good practice, what if I will have more parameters:

```
public function template($person, $country, $region) {
  ....
}
```

Then I would have to make multiple cases. Is there any helper function for eloquent to make it simpler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `when` function for condition for better code sytle like this  [see more](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#conditional-clauses)

```
$offers = Offer::when($person,function($query,$person) {
        return $query->where('person',$person);
})->where('published', true)
      ->orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate(9);
```

Comment: I'm checking this out

Comment: @Devon i think no need to import $person

Comment: Ok, you're right, the closure is passed the first argument of when as the second argument of the closure.

Comment: I think this is the best answer, and I will use this in my project. Thank you @JigneshJoisar

Answer (score 2):

Laravel offers when() which allows you to run a closure when the condition succeeds which works for chaining:

```
Offer::where('published', true)
   ->when($person, function($query) use ($person) {
       $query->where('person',$person);
   })
   ->orderBy('created_at','desc')
   ->paginate(9);
```

Although, I think it's simpler to just not chain everything in these circumstances, especially when your conditions get more complex:

```
$query = Offer::where('published', true) 
   ->orderBy('created_at','desc');

if ($person) {
    $query->where('person',$person);
}

return $query->paginate(9);
```

I assume you're also missing a `return` call in your functions which I added in the latter example.

Comment: thank you for this example, this seems simple and could help +1 from me!