# Laravel: How to remove a specific 'where' clause from the Query Builder

Tags: php, laravel

I am fairly new to laravel and need to remove a 'where clause' from the Query Builder based on search options being selected or not.
My model contains the following already in a local scope:

```
$builder->where('users.active', '=', 'Yes');
```

and I need to override this in a specific search circumstance to either allow values of 'Yes' and 'No', or just remove the clause entirely.  This must be done in a Trait and be suitable for multi uses/models.

I have actually got this to work by adding a new method in my SearchTrait that strips the query builder apart, removes the offending column and associated binding and returns the modified query builder.

```
$builder = static::removeWhere($builder, 'users.active');
```

This seems to work - but my question(s) are:

- Is this a suitable solution, or is there something more elegant?
- Are there any glaring issues with my solution?
- Is there a better place for this / can I easily extend the 'builder'?

```
    /**
     * @param Builder $builder
     * @param $whereColumn
     * @return Builder
     */
    public static function removeWhere(Builder $builder, $whereColumn)
    {
        $bindings = $builder->getQuery()->bindings['where'];
        $wheres = $builder->getQuery()->wheres;

        $whereKey = false;
        foreach ($wheres as $key => $where) {
            if ($where['column'] == $whereColumn) {
                $whereKey = $key;
                break;
            }
        }

        if ($whereKey !== false) {
            unset($bindings[$whereKey]);
            unset($wheres[$whereKey]);
        }

        $builder->getQuery()->wheres = $wheres;
        $builder->getQuery()->bindings['where'] = $bindings;

        return $builder;
    }
```

Comment: Laravel has `withoutGlobalScope()`: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#global-scopes, section "_Removing Global Scopes_", see if that makes it any easier

Comment: Thanks @kerbholz - I actually should have written 'in a local scope' (I have updated the question) but your suggestion certainly has potential.

Comment: I guess "Just don't use the local scope if it's not needed" is not a viable solution? Good luck though

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel conditional where with eloquent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52759680/laravel-conditional-where-with-eloquent)

Comment: Use `when($condition, $queryCallback)` as answered in the suggested question. As you are building your query anyway, just don't attach conditions to it you don't want instead of removing them afterwards (which seems cumbersome and dangerous to me).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is "academically correct", but this is working for me:

```php
$query = Model::whereIn('id', [1,2,3]);

$count = $query->count();
$countCondition1 = $query->where('condition1', 1)->count();

array_pop ($query->getQuery()->bindings['where']);
array_pop ($query->getQuery()->wheres);

$countCondition2 = $query->where('condition2', 1)->count();

array_pop ($query->getQuery()->bindings['where']);
array_pop ($query->getQuery()->wheres);

$countCondition3 = $query->where('condition3', 1)->count();

// ...
```